# gcc: how much does gprof slow down a programm?

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, gprof

I have a self written software which communicates with a laser scanner from hokuyo (http://www.hokuyo-aut.jp/02sensor/07scanner/urg_04lx_ug01.html, often used in ROS, but my application does not use any ROS dependencies). The SW ist written for linux and runs on a raspberry pi and a normal laptop.

To determine the load of individual program pices (I have three threads etc.) I compiled with `g++ [...] -pg [...]` to watch the load with gprof. When running the SW from time to time(not determenistic) the answer of the sensor runs in a timeout(for those who knows the urg_library, the lib returns error Code `-5 = URG_NO_RESPONSE`. I think it comes from the `-pg` option, because of

- not compiling with `-pg` does not runs into this error
- when the error is happened, it works to reconnect to the sensor
- other errors can be excluded because of tests (others usb-cables, measurement of the current consumption etc.)
- the error happens more then one time in a run (when this error happens, I try to reconnect which always works), but only with the `-pg` option it runs into this errors

Are there any informations about how does the profiling option has affect on the running time or does anybody have similar problems with communication to hardware?

Comment: gprof uses some function-entry code to count how many times function A calls function B. That involves identifying A and locating the (A,B) entry in a table so the counter can be bumped. If B is a small function called lots of times, the overhead can be quite a bit.